# How to use asyncio event loop in library function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio, event-loop

I'm trying to create a function performing some asynchronous operations using asyncio, **users of this function should not need to know that asyncio is involved under the hood**.
I'm having a very hard time understanding how this shall be done with the asyncio API as most functions seem to operate under some global loop-variable accessed with get_event_loop and calls to this are affected by the global state inside this loop.

I have four examples here where two (foo1 and foo3) seem to be reasonable use cases but they all show very strange behaviors:

```
async def bar(loop):
    # Disregard how simple this is, it's just for example
    s = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("ls", loop=loop)


def foo1():
    # Example1: Just use get_event_loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(bar(loop), 1000))
    # On exit this is written to stderr:
    #    Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True debug=False>>
    #    Traceback (most recent call last):
    #      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in __del__
    #      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 65, in close
    #      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 146, in remove_signal_handler
    #      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    #    TypeError: signal handler must be signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL, or a callable object


def foo2():
    # Example2: Use get_event_loop and close it when done
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(bar(loop), 1000))  # RuntimeError: Event loop is closed  --- if foo2() is called twice
    loop.close()


def foo3():
    # Example3: Always use new_event_loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(bar(loop), 1000)) #RuntimeError: Cannot add child handler, the child watcher does not have a loop attached
    loop.close()


def foo4():
    # Example4: Same as foo3 but also set_event_loop to the newly created one
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)        # Polutes global event loop, callers of foo4 does not expect this.
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(bar(loop), 1000))  # OK
    loop.close()
```

None of these functions work and i don't see any other obvious way to do it, how is asyncio supposed to be used? It's seems like it's only designed to be used under the assumption that the entry point of the application is the only place where you can create and close the global loop. Do i have to fiddle around with event loop policies?

foo3 seems like the correct solution but i get an error even though i explicitly pass along loop, because deep down inside create_subprocess_exec it is using the current policy to get a new loop which is None, is this a bug in asyncio subprocess?

I'm using Python 3.5.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: You should wrap with async and await the functions inside all of foo functions, like you did with bar.

Comment: You should never call `close()` on an object you did not create.  You're shutting down a global event loop which doesn't belong to you.  Just don't do that.

Comment: In example1 i don't close the loop, but that gives the user of foo1 the obligation to close the loop. The user of my library should not need to know that asyncio is involved.

Answer (score 2):

**foo1** error happens because you didn't close event loop, see this [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue23548).

**foo2** because you can't reuse closed event loop.

**foo3** because you didn't set new event loop as global.

**foo4** is almost what you want, all you left to do is store old event loop and set it back as global after bar executed:

```
import asyncio


async def bar():
    # After you set new event loop global,
    # there's no need to pass loop as param to bar or anywhere else.
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("ls")
    await process.communicate()


def sync_exec(coro):  # foo5
    old_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    finally:
        loop.close()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(old_loop)


sync_exec(asyncio.wait_for(bar(), 1000))
```

**One more important thing:** it's not clear why you want to hide using of asyncio behind some sync functions, but usually it's bad idea. Whole thing about one global event loop is to allow user to run different concurrent jobs in this single event loop. You're trying to take away this possibility. I think you should reconsider this decision.

Comment: Nice try but it has the same problem as foo1(), when the program exits you get some ignored exception written to stderr because old_loop is never closed.

Comment: The reason i'm hiding it is because i have multiple I/O bound asynchrounous tasks that i want to merge into one result using asyncio.gather, i want to run all these sub-tasks as asyncio but the final operation as a whole doesn't matter if it is synchronous. Maybe this is the wrong mindset and i should just expose even the final result as an async function, although i think most of my users would be confused by all this, they dont want to set up their own event loop, instead they just want a convenience function that only gives the result synchronously.

Comment: `same problem as foo1()` - sorry, I can't test on Linux, am I right you tried code from my answer and it gives you error? If so, looks like problem is more about `create_subprocess_exec` neither then about event loop manipulations. You can try something like [this](https://bugs.python.org/msg240248). May be this would be fixed in Python 3.7 or later, see [this PR](https://github.com/python/asyncio/pull/456).

Comment: `i think most of my users ... dont want to set up their own event loop` - nothing stops you from providing function that do job synchronously, but in the same time I think it at least shouldn't be **only** option. Some of your users may want to run your tasks and theirs own tasks parallely. To make it happen you should probably also provide coroutines.

Comment: Yes, i tried to run it, exactly same error as foo1(). Running on Python 3.5.3 on Linux, I don't get any error if running in debugger though so likely something environment related. Your linked PR looks promising, have to try 3.6.

Comment: Just tried 3.6.1 and there foo1() works. Nothing is printed to stderr on exit.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Python 3.6, then foo1() will work, without the need to explicitly close the default event loop.

Not the answer i was hoping for as we only use 3.5 :(